# How to add a new column to a pandas dataframe while calculate the elements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I want to add a new column to a pandas df which will be calculated based on another column. 
Here's a shourtcut of the df:

[image: shortcut of df]

If the date is between `start_date1` and `end_date1` it should output in the period column "0". If the date is between `start_date2` and `end_date2` output a "1" and so on.

Is there any way to do this without a loop?

Thanks for your help :)

Larry

Comment: Welcome to SO! please provide a sample example. Please do a quick read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check if your column `date` has a `datetime` format.

You can check this with `df.dtypes`. If it does not have the format date (`datetime64`), you have to convert it to datetime with:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

Please note that the argument `errors='ignore'` has its risks, so its optional.

Now to make your calculated field, you can do this:

```
# define function to calculate periods based on date
def calculate_period(row): 
    if row['date'] > start_date1 & row['date'] < end_date1:
        return "0"

    elif row['date'] > start_date2 & row['date'] < end_date2:
        return "1"

    elif row['date'] > start_date3 & row['date'] < end_date3:
        return "2"

    else:
        return "unknown"


# apply function to create the new column
df['period'] = df.apply(calculate_period, axis=1)
```

If you need more `period` values, you can extend the `elif` statements as you like.

Since there is lack of information about your data. I assumed that `start_date1` and `end_date1` are variables you defined.

If these are columns as well. The function would look like this:

```
# define function to calculate periods based on date
def calculate_period(row): 
    if row['date'] > row['start_date1'] & row['date'] < row['end_date1']:
        return "0"

    elif row['date'] > row['start_date2'] & row['date'] < row['end_date2']:
        return "1"

    elif row['date'] > row['start_date3'] & row['date'] < row['end_date3']:
        return "2"

    else:
        return "unknown"


# apply function to create the new column
df['period'] = df.apply(calculate_period, axis=1)
```

Good luck.